# asp.net applications running without IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis-5

I have been using windows XP. I installed visual studio 2008 and sql server 2005. It has been removed suddenly due to some system corruption. I installed it again the visual studio 2008, IIS is not enabled in control panel too, but my applications is running.. whats going behind?Is it possible to run asp.net applications without enabling the IIS?

Will this cause any problems while developing the application?

Comment: Does it have random port numbers in their urls? Eg: `localhost:92123/Page.aspx`

Comment: yes,the port numbers are random its like http://localhost:1111/sess.aspx

Comment: So its using the built-in web server for VS. You can start adding the IIS again in your OS if you want to use IIS5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Visual Studio comes Built in web server for development purposes, you may be using it.